# Diophantine equation, what is $m-q$?

Tags: number-theory

**Problem:** If $m^3=n^4$, $p^5=q^6$ and $n-p=61$, what is $m-q$ ?

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E3%20%3D%20b%5E4,%20where%20a,b%20are%20positive%20integers), the only positive integer solutions for the equation $m^3=n^3$ is $(m,n)=(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. So I don't see how $1-p=61$ for a positive integer $p$.

Any ideas how to attack this problem?

Comment: How did you deduce that? I got this problem on another forum.

Comment: Hint: When m, n, p and q are all even, $m^3 \equiv 0 \pmod 8, n^4 \equiv 0 \pmod 16, p^5 \equiv 0 \pmod 32, q^6 \equiv 0 \pmod 64

Comment: You get it by comparing the number of times a prime divides both sides of the equation $m^3 = n^4$, and $p^5 = q^6$. But I don't see why an arbitrary $3$rd power and $5$th power (forgive the earlier comment) can't differ by $61$. Surely there is a logic to it.

Comment: What I don't get is this: Why does $m^3=n^4$ only have the solutions $(0,0),(1,1)$?

Comment: Me neither. Obviously it's not true since $1000^4 = 10000^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Suppose: m^3=n^4=j^{12} \space and \space p^5=q^6=k^{30}$$
$$We \space get: m=j^4,n=j^3 \space and \space p=k^6,q=k^5$$
$n-p=61$

$j^3-k^6=61$

$We \space know \space that: a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

$and \space we \space let \space a=j \space and \space b=k^2$

$\text{Therefore the expression can be factored into:}$
$(j-k^2)(j^2+jk^2+k^4)=61$

$Obviously, \space j-k^2 \lt j^2+jk^2+k^4$ 
$\text{and since 61 is prime, we get:}$

$j-k^2=1 \to j=k^2+1$

$j^2+jk^2+k^4=61 \to (k^2+1)^2+(k^2+1)k^2+k^4=61$

$\text{Simplifying, we get:}$
$3k^4+3k^2+1=61 \to 3k^4+3k^2-60=0$

$k^4+k^2-20=0 \to (k^2+5)(k^2-4)=0$

$\text{Since k is a positive real, we only consider the case when} \space k^2-4=0$

$(k+2)(k-2)=0 \to k=2$

$j=k^2+1=2^2+1 \to j=5$

$Therefore, \space m-q=j^4-k^5=5^4-2^5=625-32=593$

Comment: How did you come up with equatimg them to $j^{12}$ and $k^{30}$?

Comment: lcm(3,4)=12 and lcm(5,6)=30. I let n and q be expressed as another variable(having exponents) so that we can perform algebraic manipulation and get the answer, rather than just plain n-q, which will not lead you any further.

Comment: No problem man. :)